# How to add spacing between radio buttons and submit button in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to increase space between submit button and radio button `Totally comfortable` See screenshot below:

I tried multiple css styling but none of them works:

1)

```
 form .btn-primary{
        margin-left: 140px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

2)

```
form .btn-primary{
    margin-left: 140px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

3)

```
form .btn-primary{
    margin-left: 140px;
    border-top: 30px;
}
```

None of the above css style solves the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-top`:

```
form .btn-primary{
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```